# neural network with multiplicative probability factor

Tags: neural-network, classification

I'm developing a project for the university. I have to create a classifier for a disease. The data-set i have contains several inputs (symptoms) and each of them is associated to a multiplicative probability factor (e.g. if patient has the symptom A, he has a double probability to have that disease). 
So, how can i do this type of classifier? Is there any type of neural network or other instrument to do this??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should specify how much labeled data and unlabeled data you have.

Let's assume you have only labeled data. Then you could use neural networks, but IMHO, SVM or random forests are the best techniques for a first try.

Note that if you use machine learning techniques, your prior information about symptoms (multiplicative coefficients) are not used because the labels are used instead. If you want to use these coefficients, it's no more machine learning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use neural network for this purpose also. If to speak about your situation, with binding symptom A to more chances for decease B, that is what neural network should be able to accomplish. To bind connection weights from input A ( symptom A ) to desease B. From your side, you can engrain such classification rule in case if you'll have enough training data in your training data set. Also I propose you to try two different approaches: 1. neural network with N outputs (N = number of deseases to clasif). 2. Create for each desease neural network.